# Docusing Plugin for Sugar CRM does not craete envelope with document

Tags: curl, libcurl, sugarcrm, docusignapi

I am using docusign Plugin for Sugarcrm. I have added docusign dashlet on Accounts record. when I click on "Send With Docusign" button if works fine if there is no documetn attached with given account and opens sender view with attached contacts as recipients.  but if there is document attached with given account record. It keeps on loading for long time then it gives following error.
'DocuSign_IOException' with message '**SSL read: error:00000000 lib(0):func(0: reason(0): errno :10054**' on DocuSign_CurlIO.php line 63. which is '**$result = curl_exec($curl);**'. if I display curl_errno($curl); it gives me **56**

Kindly suggest me what to do. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a Connector that is written and maintained by SugarCRM, not DocuSign, and I'm not sure if Sugar monitors these dev forums.  You'll probably have to reach out to Sugar through their own support channels...

Comment: Thanks Ergin, for your response. I shifted to new linux server where https  is enabled. Now it is working fine.